# What is it when everything gradually freezes except cursor keeps moving?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, freeze, cursor

I have a dual boot setup in my PC having Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20. In both the operating systems, sometimes after logging in, clicks stop working in some part of the UI. Gradually rights click stops working, key boards buttons stop working and in the end sometimes everything freezes, except only the cursor keeps moving.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Dead battery RF keyboard?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No! the laptop's touch pad also stops.